# What is the Apache Tomcat equivalent of virtualhost of Apache httpd?

Tags: virtualhost, tomcat, apache2

In Apache httpd, if I want to link a web application with a domain name I create a virtualhost.

In Apache Tomcat, if I want to link a web application, is there a equivalent method?

Comment: I removed your references to the operating systems, because they are of absolutely no relevance. You can run Apache httpd both on Linux and on Windows, and you can run Apache Tomcat both on Linux and Windows. In both cases the servers work exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtual hosting is a feature of the HTTP/1.1 protocol, provided by the `Host` HTTP header [RFC 7230, 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4). Every modern web server supports it, but the configuration directives have a bit different names and formats:

- [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) (`VirtualHost`)

  ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias www.example.com
       DocumentRoot "/var/www/examplecom"
   </VirtualHost>
  ```
- [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) (Server Blocks)

  ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name example.com www.example.com;
       root /var/www/examplecom;
       location / { 
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
       }
   }
  ```
- IIS ([Binding `<binding>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding))

  ```
   <site name="Example" id="2">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="Example">
         <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\examplecom" />
      </application>
      <bindings>
         <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:example.com" />
         <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:www.example.com" />
      </bindings>
   </site>
  ```
- [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) (`<Host />`)

  ```
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="example.com">
       <Host name="example.com" appBase="webapps_examplecom">
           <Alias>www.example.com</Alias>
       </Host>
   </Engine>
  ```
- [Lighttpd](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration) (`$HTTP["host"]` *match on host* is actually closest to the protocol)

  ```
   HTTP["host"] =~ "^(|www\.)example\.com$" {
       server.document-root = "/var/www/examplecom"
   }
  ```